# Can the iOS 6 setup assistant be re-run a second time without erasing my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

After upgrading my 3GS to iOS 6, I had to make an urgent phone call. Thus, when the iOS 6 setup wizard showed, I just hit "skip", "continue", and "accept" whenever possible.

Now that the phone call is made and I have time to spare, I'd like to go through the setup again. Is it possible to restart the setup wizard (without having to restore my device and reinstall iOS 6)?

If this is not possible, which settings should I check and which steps should I take to make sure everything is set up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly - perhaps others can help flesh out any missing details - the setup wizard primarily lets you sign in with / sign up for an Apple ID to use for iCloud, it asks you to agree to the iCloud Terms of Service, and it asks about setting up Location Services.

All of these can be accessed directly through the Settings app at any time. I don't believe you will miss any important functionality by missing the wizard, especially if you were previously using your iPhone with iCloud in iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. After a reboot, you will be on the setup screen.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to erase the content of the device.

Comment: But you did not set it up, so that means you won’t have any content, right?

Comment: My 3GS had iOS5, had a lot of stuff installed and was working fine. I *upgraded* it to iOS6, keeping all the content. At the end of the upgrade, a setup wizard started and I canceled it. No content was lost, I'm just worried that some new iOS6 feature might not be set up correctly.

Comment: This is the only way to get the activation assistant. Erase everything here or restore it connected to iTunes. The assistant is a one time tool that needs a totally clean slate to do it's work. It can't leave some settings alone and write others.

Answer (score 0):

Rather choose Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings. This will just reset all the customized settings and will not remove your data which the other answer will do.

Comment: It won’t restart the setup.

Comment: I just tried it on one of my devices and after it restarted automatically, it took me through all the steps that one goes through to setup the device (this is longer than the one after the iOS 6 upgrade which is a subset of these). Perhaps try shutting it down and restarting, unfortunately I don't have a 3GS to test with.

Comment: But OP won’t be able to restore apps and music if only settings are reset.

Comment: If you read his question, it is his device, he just wants to rerun the wizard, not restore to default and not re-install apps. That is why I suggested this process.

Comment: On my 3GS, it reset the settings but it did not start the wizard again (even after a manual restart).

Comment: See? It doesn’t restart the setup.

Comment: This doesn't work – the setup assistant doesn't rerun. However: Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings and also Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings, followed by power off, power on enabled the service that otherwise only works with setup assistant (Verizon existing customers iPhone 6)